# Putting a value in a sublist

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have data as follows:

```
alist <- list()
vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

I want to put a value (in this case an object), into a sublist. But when I do:

```
for (i in 1:length(vec)) {
  alist[[i]][1] <- vec
}
```

this is for some reason not allowed: `Error in *tmp* [[i]] : subscript out of bounds`.
Do I have to intialise every sublist? If so, what is the syntax for doing that?

Desired outcome:

```
desired_out <- list( list(alist = c(1, 2, 3) ), list(alist = c(1, 2, 3) ), list(alist = c(1, 2, 3) ))
```

## EDIT:

An attempt to create a reproducible example for the entire loop (my actual data is a loop within a loop):

```
alist <- list()
vec <- c(1, 2, 3)

for (j in 1:2) {
  for (i in 1:length(vec)) {
  alist[[i]][j] <- vec
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `alist[[i]] <- vec`?

Comment: Or `alist[[i]] <- list(vec)` if it should be the first list element.

Comment: @nicola Thank you for your comment. The actual code is a loop within a loop because of which just `alist[[i]] <- vec` would overwrite the first list item.

Comment: Can you please state what you expected outcome is?

Comment: `alist` is a function, such naming is misleading.

Comment: @utubun Did not know that, will use another name next time

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for adding the `desired_output`. I have trouble creating that base on the input vec `c(1,2,3)`.  Could you update the inputs as well?

Comment: @TimTeaFan I updated the output to reflect the input. Thank you for the patience

Comment: With your edit, now the desired output is not correct, right?

Comment: @zx8754 Indeed it is no longer correct, I thought I would create a very simple example (because I thought the answer would be simple). It bit me in the behind a little.

Comment: Your original solution would work if you use double brackets instead of `alist[[ i ]][ 1 ]` try `alist[[ i ]][[ 1 ]]`, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty list with length then fill it in:

```
x <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)

for (j in 1:2) {
  for (i in 1:length(vec)) {
    # notice double square brackets
    x[[ i ]][[ j ]] <- vec
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you ask for, but I think your example is still to minimal for your original nested loop problem:

```r
alist <- list()
vec <- c(1, 2, 3)

for (i in 1:length(vec)) {
  alist[[i]] <- list(alist = vec)
}

desired_out <- list(
                  list(alist = c(1, 2, 3)),
                  list(alist = c(1, 2, 3)),
                  list(alist = c(1, 2, 3))
                  )

identical(alist, desired_out)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. I indeed noticed that I made my example to easy.. My apologies, I am bit (actually a lot) in a hurry. It almost worked though. The only problem is that the `list(alist = vec)` part gets overwritten by the outer loop. So I need to add an index to it somehow.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for the explanation. If you say the outer loop overwrites the inner loop, then I think we would need this in the minimal example. At the moment we are writing into an empty list. So the outer loop needs to wrte something in the list too, otherwise it can't get overwritten. I wonder, is your double loop writing into an empty list? Or is it changing an existing list?

Comment: I will add it asap, to improve the question for others. I was able to solve the problem for myself with zx's answer. Thank you very much for your help!